# Regression models as column in data table, R

Tags: r, data.table, regression, lapply

I am struggling to find a way how to use the power of data tables while running some regression models.

Here is a simplified working case:

```
# given a data table containing desired variables
MyVarb <- data.table(Y=rnorm(100),
                 V1=rnorm(100),
                 V2=rnorm(100))

# given a new data table containing a series of formulas/equations in a column
DT <- data.table(eq=c("Y ~ V1", "Y ~ V2", "Y ~ V1 + V2"))

# I store the linear regression models in a second column
DT[, "models" := lapply(eq, function(i) lm(i, data=MyVarb))]

# Now, I can access the coefficients of a model (e.g. the 3rd one) like:
DT[3, models][[1]]$coefficients
(Intercept)          V1          V2 
-0.01583034  0.08284029  0.01630247
```

However, I am curious if there are alternative ways.
This doesn't work as desired:

```
DT[, "trial" := lm(eq, data=MyVarb)]
# ***sorry for my bad understanding of data tables and objects***
```

I am curious and I want to run thousands of models and there are many more variables, therefore it is time consuming using the `lapply` inside the data table `DT` (couple of hours on my PC and then I run out of the 8Gb of RAM...). Is there a way how to code it faster?

I would appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Do you need to store the whole model objects? If yes, why? Often it is sufficient to store coefficients and some statistics. Anyway, your speed limiting part is actually `lm` and parsing of the formulas within `lm`. Look for alternatives (there are some). It would be quite fast if you could create the design matrix yourself and use `lm.fit`.

Comment: Yeah, `lapply` is the way to store them, one in each row. `"trial" := lm(eq, data=MyVarb)` doesn't work because `lm` doesn't take a vector of equations. To avoid memory problems, you can instead use a loop (so only one model is dealt with at a time); but I guess thousands of regression models will always mean trouble...

Comment: @Roland, I am actually interested in the coefficients, p-values and AIC. Anyway, I was thinking to store the models as such...just in case of future queries or so.

Comment: Inspect a `lm` object using `str` and you'll see that it is a quite large object.   Storing thousands of these "just in case" is not a good idea.

Comment: @Frank, do you mean by loop something like this?: `for (i in 1:nrow(DT)) set(DT, j="trial", value = list(model=list(lm(DT[,eq][i], data=MyVarb))))`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the coefficients, p-values and AIC then this will work while not using up a bunch of memory storing unnecessary bits of lm objects

```
MyVarb <- data.table(Y=rnorm(100),
                     V1=rnorm(100),
                     V2=rnorm(100))
eq=c("Y ~ V1", "Y ~ V2", "Y ~ V1 + V2")
DT<-rbindlist(lapply(eq, function(mod) {
  reg<-lm(mod, data=MyVarb)
  dt<-data.table(summary(reg)$coefficients)
  dt[,coef:=row.names(summary(reg)$coefficients)]
  dt[,aic:=AIC(reg)]
  dt[,model:=mod]


}))
```